# Triggering event upon loss of focus on select menu

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a bunch of rows where I wish to replace the content of the cell with a select menu when clicked.  I am thinking of something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/dRZmQ/1/

```
 $("#my-table tbody").on("click", "td.edit", function(){
    var $t=$(this),role=$t.text();
    $t.html($("#select-clone").clone(false).removeAttr('id'));
 }).on("change", "td.edit", function(){
    alert('change');
 }).on("blur", "td.edit", function(){
    alert('blur');
 });
```

The above code almost works, but for some reason, the select menu closes if the mouse button is not pressed.

Now, when the select menu loses focus, I wish to trigger an event which replaces the select menu with the original text.  I've been playing around with blur(), but haven't gotten it working.  And when the select menu is changed, I wish to trigger an event where I can save the data and again replace the select menu with selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1)

**To solve your first issue**, you need to remember that you are appending a `select` to an element with a `click` event! So every time you `click` on the `select`, you are triggering the `click` on the `.edit`... the browser just goes around and around, that's why you are forced to keep the `mousedown` during the selection process.

To fix it, just add a `span` and bind the click to the span, keeping the `select` appended to the `.edit`:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/NAHXR/) Example!

**RELEVANT HTML**

```
<tbody>
  <tr><td>xxx</td><td class="edit"><span>yyy</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td>xxx</td><td class="edit"><span>yyy</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td>xxx</td><td class="edit"><span>yyy</span></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

**jQUERY**

```
$("#my-table td.edit").on("click", "span", function(){
  var $t    = $(this),
      $html = $t.parent(),
      role  = $t.text();
  
  $html.html($("#select-clone").clone(false).removeAttr('id'));
});
```

---

### 2)

To have the selected option text placed on your `.edit`, you just need to bind an event handler to the `change`, and collect the `HTML` from the selected `option`:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/NAHXR/3/) Example!

**jQuery**

```
$('.edit').on("change", "select", function() {
  var $t2 = $(this),
      val = $(this).find(':selected').html();

  $t2.parent().html(val);
});
```

---

### 3)

To have the step 01 e 02 looping, you need to wrap the value from the selected `option` into a `span` to keep the `click` event firing when the user clicks the text:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/NAHXR/5/) Example!

**jQuery**

```
$('.edit').on("change", "select", function() {
  var $t2   = $(this),
      $span = $('<span>'),
      val   = $span.html($(this).find(':selected').html());

  $t2.parent().html(val);
});
```

Comment: Very nice answer!  I am going through it as we speak.  Thank you

Comment: Great tricky use of span.  It was the looping clicks that had me stumped!  The only other part is if someone clicks off the select, it needs to revert to the original.